# Android database connectivity exception

Tags: android

I am trying to make an android (2.3) connection with MySQL. The code is below:

```
public class ConnectionClass {


static String user = "root";


public static void main() {
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mydatabase";
//  String url = "jdbc:mysql://10.2.5.69:3306/test";
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        ***Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, "mypassword");***
        con.isReadOnly();
        System.out.println("success");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from user");
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("id" + rs.getInt(1));
            System.out.println("data" + rs.getString(2));
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

but at the line `Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, "mypassword")` I get the exception:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Answer (score 0):

Well I didnt find anything wrong with your code..
But if you  want to connect to mysql at any cost,I would suggest an alternate method of using php as an mediator, which can do all the operations which is mentioned and accessing this php file though HttpClient in java
ref:http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database

Answer (score -1):

Android doesn't support for MySQL database.

See the official documentation here:

> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db